# WordPress not found when using wget

Tags: software-installation, wget, wordpress

When I run `wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz` in my Ubuntu 16.04 server, I get this result:

---

[image: wget]

---

I have tried other sources but they do not have the specific error that I do.

It seems to not find wordpress.org and I do not know why. Could it be a DNS issue?

Comment: It certainly looks like a DNS issue. Can you reach other hosts from that box, like google.com?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution.

All I have to do is just add the IP address and domain name to the `/etc/hosts` file.

Like so:

[image]

This hack solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a DNS or network issue at your end. If you look at the error message you are getting, it indicates a name resolution issue.

`Resolving wordpress.org(wordpress.org)...failed: Temporary failure in name resolution.
wget: unable to resolve host address 'wordpress.org'`

- First you should check your general internet connectivity by pinging a known public IP address e.g. `ping -c1 8.8.8.8`, which is Google DNS server.
- If you get a positive response then you should check the contents of your `/etc/resolv.conf` file, which contains DNS resolver servers (typically provided by your ISP or hypervisor or DHCP server). You can try pinging those IP addresses also.
- For a quick test you can replace the contents of your current resolv.conf file to the following. Make sure to backup your current contents first and also ensure that the first ping test I suggested above, works.

  `nameserver 9.9.9.9
  nameserver 8.8.8.8
  nameserver 8.8.4.4`
- Try doing an nslookup `nslookup wordpress.org 9.9.9.9`
- The nsswitch file defines the search order `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. Look for a line something like `hosts: files dns mdns4` and the look for line looking like `order hosts,bind,nis`
- Do you have a local firewall preventing access to UDP port 53 as that is what is used by DNS.

Comment: I pinged and that works. I checked the contents of `resolv.conf` and there was nothing in it. So I made a backup and added the nameservers you said to add to `resolv.conf`, and it still does not work.

Comment: The solution which you have posted below is not the right way to do. As if tomorrow wordpress.org changes its IP address, you would need to make the changed again at your end. This is why DNS is there. Try the following commands  `nslookup wordpress.org 9.9.9.9`. Post the results. Do you have a firewall which is blocking outgoing UDP connections to PORT 53?